# Hiding zero value in line, column and stack charts

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have 3 different charts (line, column and stack charts), and I need to display data where value is greater than zero meaning if it's zero or null I don't want that particular day to show in any of my charts. (see below). The example below the Day 9 is zero or null and it should not appear in the chart.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Could go into the visibility and say something like

```
=IIF(Fileds!zerovalue.Value < 0, true, false)
```

This will hide the values that are less than zero,

another option is to go into the group properties and use the filter option to filter out the values that are less than 0.

Comment: There is no visibility configuration in the line chart Y or X axis?